# End program when an event is met VB6

Tags: vb6

Here is my code(partial), when a guest guessed 3 times.

```
If (counter = 3) And (rx.EOF = True) Then
    MsgBox "You guessed too many times! Intruder alert!"
    End
    .
    .

    .
```

Is there a best way to end/freeze this user to protect the program?
Any idea will help.

Answer (score 3):

[End is evil](http://web.archive.org/web/20090306153232/http://www.obob.com/cis58/evilend.html), which claims:

> ... if your program does not exit cleanly without an `End` Statement, then
> your program contains a bug or bugs. Take out the end statement, and
> do whatever testing it takes to clean up whatever you had failed to
> clean up previously.

`End` is deprecated [in the VB6 manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243356(VS.60).aspx) because it suppresses cleanup events like `Form_Unload` and `Class_Terminate`. Here's an excerpt from the VB6 manual `End` [topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243356(VS.60).aspx):

> **Note** The End statement stops code
> execution abruptly.
> Code you have placed in the Unload,
> QueryUnload, and Terminate events of
> forms and class modules is not
> executed...

> The End statement provides a way to
> force your program to halt. For normal
> termination of a Visual Basic program,
> you should unload all forms.

Comment: what other options can i choose, except End?

Comment: Ensure that you Unload all forms closes the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can unload all forms

for example a project which lets you load extra forms, and unload them all

```
'1 form with:
'  2 command buttons: name=Command1   name=Command2

Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim frm As New Form1
  frm.Caption = CStr(Now)
  frm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  UnloadAll
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Command1.Caption = "load extra"
  Command2.Caption = "unload all"
End Sub

Private Sub UnloadAll()
  Dim frm As Form
  For Each frm In Forms
    If frm.hWnd <> Me.hWnd Then
      Unload frm
    End If
  Next frm
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

Be careful though if you have any (neverending) loops running. You need to make sure those are finished first.
Also pay attention to controls which are connected to other devices/applications/...